# TomEE Maven plugin: Deployment path

Tags: maven, apache-tomee

When deplyoing a webapp using the tomee-maven-plugin, the effective URL the application is hosted on results to:

```
http://localhost:8080/[artifactId]-[version]/
```

I would like to set that relative path arbitrarily, like e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice/
```

Which configuration parameter in the tomee-maven-plugin does that?

Thanks for a quick hand and best regards

Pascal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably get that context path because it is the name of the warfile artifact.

You can set the `finalName` in pomfile:

```
 <build>
     <finalName>myservice</finalName>
     [ all other configuration ... ]
 </build>
```

This will produce a `myservice.war` file. If you want just to use a different context path without having a differently named artifact, you can specify it in the plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>myservice</finalName>
    <warFile>point this to your warfile</warFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or alternatively, you can try to add a `META-INF/context.xml` to your artifact, containing:

```
<Context path="/myservice" />
```

Comment: Thx for your input! I tried running maven with "-Dtomee-plugin.finalName=codenation-service", but it didn't change the resulting deployment URL.

Comment: But the "context.xml" thing has worked :-) . Though I'd prefer the parameter option.

Comment: Parameter or not does not change much. Put ${your.property} in the context path and configure the resource as filtered. Or put the property directly in the pomfile finalName and pass the value as a parameter. In general btw I would suggest against relying too uch on parameters and using profiles for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thx, mate, that worked. I ended up using the filtered resource version.

Comment: add <path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</path> to configuration

Answer (score 3):

Guido's bogus answer (with 3 upvotes!) wasted a lot of my time. It's full of bad advice.

Responding to Guido's three pieces of advice:

- "Set the warfile name in the `<build>` tag" - This is not good advice. You lose your versioning information of your artifact, and to rename your wars to make a deployment plugin happy is entirely bass-ackwards.
- "`<finalName>` tag" - This is either outdated information or flagrant misinformation. Either way, it--and the lack of documentation on the plugin--cost me a significant amount of time. See below for the real answer.
- "Create a `META-INF/context.xml` in our artifact" - This is technically true but semi-useless advice. Per the [apache documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) for Tomcat/Tomee:

> When `autoDeploy` or `deployOnStartup` operations are performed by a Host, the name and context path of the web application are derived from the name(s) of the file(s) that define(s) the web application. Consequently, the **context path may not be defined** in a `META-INF/context.xml`

If Guido deletes his answer, all of the above can be removed.

To specify the context path for a web app in the tomee-maven-plugin:

```
<configuration>
...
    <context>${artifactId}</context>
...
</configuration>
```

This will, for example, deploy `myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` as `/myapp`.

Also, while I'm ranting, I may as well make the world a better place and add what else I've learned, since the [tomee-maven-plugin's homepage](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-maven-plugin.html) contains virtually no information about the available configuration options...

- Try running with `-X`, it prints out an XML block of the current XML configuration. (e.g. "`mvn tomee:run -X` and look for "`<configuration>`").
- If you're transitioning from the `tomcat-maven-plugin` to the `tomee-maven-plugin`, you can't use any of your existing configuration. Throw it away.
- [The author of the tomee-maven-plugin](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com) only provides documentation in random blog posts, so look there if you have issues or even better troll through all the OpenEJB source code. Grrr...
- If you're using SSL certs there's also little information about what it takes to get up and running:

First, there's an undocumented "classpaths" tag that may be useful to you:

```
<classpaths>
    <classpath>${someClasspath}</classpath>
</classpaths>
```

Secondly, there's an undocumented `systemVariables` tag that you can use, (or you could use `<args>`) to specify your keystore and truststore. It looks obvious below, but nowhere else actually tells you what the tomee-maven-plugin expects, and there's a fair amount of misinformation as well (e.g. that any JKS in the conf will be auto-loaded), so here's what *actually works*:

```
<systemVariables>
    <javax.net.ssl.trustStore>${some.path}/truststore.jks</javax.net.ssl.trustStore>
    <javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword>somePassword</javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword>
    <javax.net.ssl.keyStore>${some.path}/keystore.pkcs12</javax.net.ssl.Store>
    <javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>somePassword</javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>
    <javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType>someType (e.g. PKCS12)</javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType>
</systemVariables>
```

Hope this helps someone someday. :-)